# Regular expression for address matching using re module

Tags: python, regex

I need to match addresses of the form: 1-3 numbers, then a space, then several words (letters) separated by spaces.

The words can contain accents (`é`, `è`, `ê`, etc.) and the words can contain dashes (`-`)

Example :

```
xxyz 01 02 03 04 123 allée pont-du-nord de la foret, 01 02 03
```

Needs to match only:

```
123 allée pont-du-nord de la forêt
```

My current regex that uses the Python `re` module:

```
\b\d{1,3}(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F]+)+'
```

This works well on the addresses, but it also matches phone numbers (and I do not want this), like:

```
01 02 03 04 05 06
```

I need the regular expression to enforce the fact that the string has a number, followed by a space, followed by one or more words (that can contain dashes `-`), the words being separated by spaces.

Comment: `-` is not a word character. Did you want to allow hyphen also?

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Seems like you might be struggling with a very difficult (if not almost impossible) problem. Have you checked for instance this discussion?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335451/regex-to-match-address-with-subpatterns

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below,

```
>>> s = 'xxyz 01 02 03 04 123 allée pont-du-nord de la foret, 01 02 03'
>>> re.search(r'(?!\b\d+\s+\d+)\b\d{1,3}(?:\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F-]+)+', s).group()
'123 allée pont-du-nord de la foret'
```

I just made two changes in the original regex.

- `(?!\b\d+\s+\d+)` this negative lookahead at the start asserts that there isn't one or more digit characters followed by a space and a digit at the start. This makes our regex to not to match the strings like `09 89`
- `\u00C0-\u017F-` By adding hyphen inside the character class, pattern inside the character class not only matches the alphabets or digits but also the hyphen symbol.

**OR**

```
>>> re.search(r'\b\d{1,3}(?:(?!\d)\s[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F-]+)+', s).group()
'123 allée pont-du-nord de la foret'
```

Comment: I ran it on this test data:

`"26 rue de l'égalité" and it matchs only "26 rue de l'"`  The " ' "  character needs to be added like the " - " was added?

Comment: then add `'` to the char class `[a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F-]` like `['a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u017F-]`

Answer (score 0):

This regex finds your desired match in your test string:

```
\b\d{1,3}\s[a-zA-Zéèê -]+\b
```

The hyphen needs to be at the end of the character class to not count as a range operator.

**edit:** Oh Python 2… here you go:

```
r=re.compile(r"\b\d{1,3}\s(\w|[' -])+\b", re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: Hey L3viathan,
Your regex works with: "72 rue de l'Egalité 24 rue Ferdinand". I get a match on "72 rue de l'Egalité".

But your regex does not work with : "Nathalie 66 rue de l'Egalité , 0 95 08". Where I get a match on "Nathalie 66 rue de l'Egalit" without the final "é" of the address.

Comment: I tried it online too here:
https://regex101.com/r/nP4hD7/1
And I get the same result.

Comment: Can you specify which version of Python you are using?

Comment: Python 2.7.3 under linux

Comment: Ah, that explains it, I am using Python 3, which handles Unicode far better. Anyways, edited my post to include the solution, I think. See also [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/nP4hD7/2).

Comment: That seems to do the trick! I take it its the "re.UNICODE" part that fixes things?

Comment: Although the new regex picks up phone number patterns like : "06 88 60 62 3 4" or phone numbers that directly preceed addresses like this: "0 14 64 57 1 26 18 rue Verdi". Your first regex did not seem to have that problem. In the second example, only "18 rue Verdi" should match.